# Invert alternation regex

Tags: python, regex

I have an alternation regex that I want to invert but can't seem to get it working, it looks like this:

```
( |\w+-\w+| \+\w+|\w)
```

which will extract all special characters except for - in the middle of a word or + in front of a word. The problem is that I want to remove everything that is not covered by this regex but the simple solution of putting ?! in front of this doesn't work.

sample input: `-xxx xxx- xx-xx +xxx xxx+ xx+xx`
desired output: `xxx xxx xx-xx +xxx xxx xxxx`

Thanks for the help,

Mattias

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample input data?

Comment: I want this: -xxx xxx- xx-xx +xxx xxx+ xx+xx, to be converted to this: xxx xxx xx-xx +xxx xxx xxxx

Comment: is it possible to do string changes with an regex?! i thought that you only can match/extract content?

Comment: i'm thinking i want to sub everything matching the regex, for instance, i'm using python and would do re.sub(regex, '', text)

Comment: BTW your initial regex has a problem. The ` \+\w+` will never get matched since it has a space in front and a single space is preceded in your regex: `( |\w+-\w+| \+\w+|\w)`. You should change the order: `( \+\w+| |\w+-\w+|\w)`.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, are you looking for this?

```
a = "abc def,ghi remove - this keep-that foo + bar +keep!"
import re
print re.sub(r'[^\w\s+-]|(?<!\w)-(?!\w)|\+(?!\w)', '', a)
#abc defghi remove  this keep-that foo  bar +keep
```

The more accurate regexp:

```
[^\w\s+-]|^-|-$|\+$|(?<=\W)-|-(?=\W)|\+(?=\W)|(?<=\w)\+
```

Comment: this seems like a great start, however, it won't remove everything I want, see the sample input and output above, this will output the following: -xxx xxx- xx-xx +xxx xxx xx+xx, want to remove the first - and the last + as well.

Comment: @materik: maybe `r'[^\w\s+-]|(?<=\W)-|-(?=\W)|\+(?=\W)|(?<=\w)\+'`

Comment: great! thanks a lot, had to add some more cases however to cover when they occur in the beginning and the end: [^\w\s+-]|^-|-$|\+$|(?<=\W)-|-(?=\W)|\+(?=\W)|(?<=\w)\+, maybe you can make this nicer!

Comment: @materik: looks fine to me, added to the post.